# Trying to save downloaded file in the SD Card using getExternalFilesDir(), Android

Tags: android, android-external-storage, android-storage

I want to download a file and then save it to the SD card of the device. I am using getExternalFilesDir() for this, which is recommended by Android developers group as well, but when I run my app, there is a directory created for the app package in both the locations (SD card and internal memory), but the file is saved in internal memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use this thread to download :

```
 private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... Url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(Url[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
            String folder_main = "TEST1";
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);
            if (!f.exists()) {
                f.mkdirs();
            }
            int lenghtOfFile = connection .getContentLength();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);

            // Save the downloaded file
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(f + "/"
                    + movie_name_b);
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            // Error Log
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    }
}
```

Execute :

```
new DownloadFile().execute(URL_TO_DOWNLOAD);
```

It will create a folder name Test1 in your SD card. and dont forget to add permissions in Manifest :  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: As mentioned in another answer as well. I tried this as well, but it doesnt seem to work. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and `getExternalFilesDir()`, both should have worked, but they are saving the file in the internal memory.

Comment: on which API version you are checking?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) to save the files in downloads directory of your sd card.